Flat Measure Manifolds?
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a 2 dimensional Riemannian manifold and assume that a coordinate system $x^\mu$ exists such that the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ has unit determinant. What are the implications of this property? Is it that every manifold admits a coordinates system with a constant measure (metric determinant)? How about higher dimensions? (Although my main question is about 2D manifolds)

Yes you can always do this locally, suppose you have a coordinate system with measure $f(x,y)dxdy$. And if there is a new coordinate system $g,h$, the measure is $dgdh$, we have $f=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$. So let $h=y$, we have $f=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$, which we can let $g(x,y)=\int_0^{x}f(t,y)dt$.
